# How to convert createHmac from node to C#?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, node.js

I have this code in node:

```
const crypto = require('crypto')
 const token = crypto.createHmac('sha1', 'value'+'secretValue').update('value').digest('hex');
```

I need to convert to C#, but the code default to convert for sha1 in .net doesnt work (actually, the result is different from the node).

How can I convert to C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you would generate a SHA1 Hmac in C#:

```
string GenerateHmac(string input, string key)
{
    var inputBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
    var keyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);

    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(inputBytes))
    {
        using (var hmacSha1 = new HMACSHA1(keyBytes))
        {
            return hmacSha1.ComputeHash(memoryStream).Aggregate("", 
                (aggregator, singleByte) => aggregator + singleByte.ToString("X2"), aggregator => aggregator);
        }
    }
}

// somewhere in your code
var value = "value";
var secretValue = "secretValue";

var hmac = GenerateHmac(value, value + secretValue);
// hmac is "0B3A72A9AF80D0E5F2CEDDCA12EE21E90DD590DE"
```

Let me know if this isn't what you were looking for and i'll try my best to help you further!